# How to gain access to two fields through a trait, one of which is mutable, at the same time?

Tags: rust

Sorry if the title of my question is not really clear, I couldn't find a better way to word it, but hopefully the following makes more sense:

So this is (a simplification of) the code i have at the moment:

```rust
pub fn transform_vertices_in_camera(object: &mut dyn HasVertices) {
    let vertices_transformed = object.get_vertices_transformed(); // returns &mut Box<[Vec3]>
    for (i, p) in object.get_vertices().iter().enumerate() { // returns &Box<[Vec3]>
        let result = Vec3::new(); //math
        vertices_transformed[i] = result;
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because we mutably borrow object through that first call, then try to borrow it again in the loop with `get_vertices()`.

I wrote this function inside the object at first, with direct access to the fields, and this works, though this can't be the solution here because i'm trying to generalise the function to all `HasVertices` objects.

I don't want to wrap the returned values in any Mutex or other, because I don't feel that would make sense here.

I could write one function that returns a tuple with both arrays but that would feel a little silly and make the rest of the code a bit awkward when we only need one of them i feel.

This is also performance-sensitive, so the solution can't have clones or buffer arrays.

I there a way around this situation or do I have to compromise on one of those points above? Am I missing something and did i make a basic mistake?

### Edit

The solution I ended going with was to just pass the two arrays to this function, and call it from a place where we have access to object as its concrete type. (not really what i would have wanted but I didn't really want to do the tuple thing, even if it's probably the best solution there, since it would allow you to perform that function on a trait)

Comment: There is no good solution, unfortunately. You can return a tuple and have convenience methods that access parts of it.

Comment: I think returning a tuple is your best bet here. You can add trait methods with default impls to just get one of the two, to avoid the "awkward"ness. Otherwise you'll probably have to use `unsafe`. Unrelated: I think those methods should return `&mut [Vec3]` and `&[Vec3]` respectively to be the most general (I don't think `&mut Box<T>` and `&Box<T>` can do anything interesting that `&mut T` and `&T` can't).

Comment: @isaactfa Right the default impl seems like the way to go to make it less ugly. Interestingly I learned while trying to solve that issue that `unsafe` doesn't seem to resolve it here (though i didn't make a lot of efforts to try to make it work, maybe there's a convoluted way). About your unrelated remark: huh, interesting, I didn't really consider that when creating those methods but now that you point it out it makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the tip !